# MYSQL generating queries I didn't ask for in my Rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been trying to fix my app's performance and after using Datadog to try to trace the problem I found out that my application is generating a bunch of SQL queries that I have no idea where they are coming from.

The top 3 queries being generated in the image below are queries that are not related to PreparationsController#index.

[image]

When looking at my application log after calling for PreparationsController#index, the only query referring to the ingredients_receipts and ingredients_preparation models are the following (these ones I actually called for them, but as you can see, they are a simple "exists" query): [image]

Preparation.rb

[image]

PreparationsController#index

[image]

I've tried tracing it further down with DataDog but it won't go deeper than what the images are showing. I've been pulling my hairs out, any help is appreciated.

Comment: there might be callbacks in PreparationsController or in its parent controllers. also there is a possibility that some queries made in PreparationSerializer. less but there is a chance that a callback defined in Nutritionable file. can you also share them? also if your logger config set as debug you may also see the file names which made queries in your terminal

Comment: No calls are being made in PreparationSerializer, it just pulls the attributes directly from the model, same goes for nutritionable file. What is this logger config you talk about?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Please share the code of your `PreparationSerializer`. I guess you have a condition like `if ingredients.any?` or similar in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like two different log capturing methods producing slightly different results, notice that the third query in the Datadog screenshot has `select ingredients.*` so the first two that have `select ?` are not "normal" queries, so probably that placeholder is filled in with `1 as one` just like your Rails log shows.

Seeing as they both seem to be id specific, that seems likely to be an n+1 problem, and probably simple to resolve with an `includes`.

Comment: I am using bullet to detect n+1 queries yet it shows nothing while rendering this action.

Comment: Ok, so ignore that bit of my answer :)